# Phyton: модули и библиотеки

Tags: python

Помогите решить, пожалуйста:

1: Создайте модуль (модуль - программа на Python, т.е. файл с расширением .py). В нем создайте функцию создающую директории от dir_1 до dir_9 в папке из которой запущен данный код. Затем создайте вторую функцию удаляющую эти папки. Проверьте работу функций в этом же модуле.

2: Создайте модуль. В нем создайте функцию, которая принимает список и возвращает из него случайный элемент. Если список пустой функция должна вернуть None. Проверьте работу функций в этом же модуле.

```
Примечание: Список для проверки введите вручную. Или возьмите этот: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

3: Создайте модуль main.py. Из модулей реализованных в заданиях 1 и 2 сделайте импорт в main.py всех функций. Вызовите каждую функцию в main.py и проверьте что все работает как надо.

Примечание: Попробуйте импортировать как весь модуль целиком (например из задачи 1), так и отдельные функции из модуля.

в первом задании:

```
import os
import shutil


def make_dirs():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        dir = 'dir_%s' % i
        if not os.path.exists(dir):
            os.mkdir('dir_%s' % i)


def del_dirs():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        dir = 'dir_%s' % i
        if os.path.exists(dir):
            shutil.rmtree(dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_dirs()
    del_dirs()
```

дает результат: Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все файлы лежат в одной папке.
`mod_1` - модуль №1
`mod_2` - модуль №2

Запуская `mod_1` и `mod_2` вы выполняете пункты №1 и №2
Запуская `main.py` вы выполняете пункт №3

*mod_1.py:*

```
import os
import shutil


def make_dirs():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        dir = 'dir_%s' % i
        if not os.path.exists(dir):
            os.mkdir('dir_%s' % i)


def del_dirs():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        dir = 'dir_%s' % i
        if os.path.exists(dir):
            shutil.rmtree(dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_dirs()
    del_dirs()
```

*mod_2.py:*

```py
import random


def get_rand_el(li: list):
    if not li:
        return

    x = random.randrange(0, len(li))
    return li[x]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(get_rand_el(li))
```

*main.py:*

```py
from mod_1 import make_dirs, del_dirs
from mod_2 import get_rand_el


make_dirs()

del_dirs()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(get_rand_el(li))
```

*Примечание:*
Условие `__name__ == '__main__'` вернёт `True` только тогда, когда мы напрямую исполняем код. Если мы импортируем этот файл, то вернётся `False`.

Comment: Спасибо! В первом задании не должно ли директории от dir_1 до dir_9 в папке из которой запущен данный код, потому как сейчас получается "Process finished with exit code 0" и все.

Comment: @Даниил Как только вы запускаете первый пример, он создаёт и сразу удаляет папки. Вы просто не замечаете этого. Попробуйте закомментировать последнюю строку, тогда папки не удалятся и Вы сможете увидеть их.

Comment: @Даниил `Process finished with exit code 0` означает, что программа выполнилась с кодом 0, то есть без ошибок.